# Help with IK Rigging for Full Suspension Mountain Bike

Tags: rigging

I'm having some trouble with rigging a full suspension mtb. I would like to be able to grab the wheel with a control bone and move it up and down. Suspenion linkages are a bit complex and there are inherent constraints due to the geometry. Essentially I need a couple bones (bone 6 and bone 2) to limit the IK action I have set up to compress the suspension. It almost works...

[image]

I have the linkage from bone 5 (control) working to move the upper linkage and the suspension. I'm having trouble with bone 006 and 002. There is a hinge where 006 meets 002, but bone 006 and 003 are one solid piece, so the angle and distance from the head of bone 003 needs to be the same as the head of bone 006. I have been trying without a bone 6 there but locking the distance from the two pivots is crucial.

[image]

A simplified version is here:
Green represents the wheel or the input control, which is some curve based on the length of the rods. red circles are floating pivots. blue circles are fixed pivots.
[image]

Comment: for those of you who didn't understand (like me) how this works, here is a pretty nice explanation/video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1dUV6pYztg at 2min you see the animation

Comment: I would feel a lot more confident with a file to work on.  The short answer is, get rid of 6, then move tail of 3 and head of 5 to the old head of 6.  Yes, that changes the direction of 3, but so? It preserves the relationship of the solid piece that is hinged at two locations, the head of 3 and the head of 6.  But if you do that, there's not really any reason to have any IK at all anymore (not any chain length 1 IK, at least, which is my assumption, not specified in question.)  It's not clear what's supposed to move with what.

Comment: i agree with Nathan - a blend file would help a lot and support lazy helpers (like me) to be more attracted by the question.

Comment: As both red dots and green one are floating pivots, there isn't a unique solution for the system, so you have to choose how to determine the behaviour of the setup. If the system of two red dots, green one and bottom blue were considered a rigid system pivoting on bottom blue dot, there would be a unique solution, that can be easily implemented.